# Create and Mange Host Headers at runtime using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

Here i am having an requirement, I am having a web site with very few users, 
I need to give separate url  (I dont Know, weather I need to create Sub Domain or Host Header) for each user to view their portal.

Keep in mind that I am having only one web site need to come with different urls, and from the url. I need to change the look and feel (Including logo... )

If anybody finds the solution for this, Pls help me out in this issue,

Yogi,

yog240@gmail.com.

Comment: You need to a) reformat your question for readability, b) add way more information such as the version of IIS, what you've tried on your own, if it's your own hosting environment, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you have a problem that would conceptually be solved by user profiles.  Ensure that there is some kind of authentication mechanism to your site (forms if over the web, windows integrated if internal) and then hook in a profile provider.  there is an asp.net one out the box.